# Python: automated change in variable contents

Tags: python, variables, psycopg2

I have a Python function which receives numerous variables, and builds an SQL query out of them:

```
def myfunc(name=None, abbr=None, grade=None, ...)
```

These values should build an SQL query. For that purpose, Those who equal `None` should be changed to `NULL`, and those who store useful values should be embraced with `'`s:

```
name="'"+name+"\'" if name else 'NULL'
abbr="'"+abbr+"\'" if abbr else 'NULL'
...
Lots of lines here - that's my problem!
...
```

And than,

```
query="""INSERT INTO table(name, abbr, ...)
         VALUES (%(name)s, %(abbr)s, ...) """ locals()
cur.execute(query)
```

Is there a nicer, more Pythonic way to change the variable contents according to this rule?

Adam

Comment: Watch out for sql injections!

Comment: +1 ebo thanks, of course, but it's for a (very) internal use.

Comment: That's not a very good excuse.  Assembling SQL code as strings is simple inefficient.  It makes the RDBMS work harder than necessary because each bit of SQL must be reparsed because it appears unique.  Using bind variables is much, much more efficient.  Besides more reliable and easier to debug.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I will appreciate some links about the subject (Python, psycopg2) as I'm not really sure about the correct syntax, and din't find anything useful on Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to form a SQL query is not by string-formatting -- the `execute` method of a `cursor` object takes a query string *with placeholders* and a sequence (or dict, depending on the exact implementation you have of the DB API) with the values to substitute there; it will then perform the None-to-Null and string-quoting that you require.

I strongly recommend you look into that possibility.  If you need string processing for some other purpose, however, you could do something like:

```
processed = dict((n, "'%s'" % v if v is not None else 'NULL')
                 for n, v in locals().iteritems())
```

and then use dictionary `processed` instead of `locals()` for further string-formatting.

Comment: Do you have a link for some materials regarding formatting a query with placeholders?

Comment: @Adam, for example, for the sqlite that's bundled with Python in the standard library, see http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html?highlight=sqlite#sqlite3.Cursor.execute -- other DB API adapters use different markers than '?', e.g. '%s' in MySQLDB, etc, etc.

Comment: Great, thanks, I found it in my search and wondered if its relevant.

Comment: @Adam Matan: Relevant doesn't begin to describe how central it is.  It's the only sane way to bind values into SQL statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could define `myfunc` as follows:

```
def myfunc(*args, **kwargs)
```

Where kwargs is a dictionary holding all named parameters passed to the function.

To get the value of a query parameter, you would use `kwargs.get(name_of_parameter, 'NULL')`. To build the query, you would just iterate over all dictionary items. Note however, that any parameter passed as a named parameter to the function will end up in the query if you do it this way.

Comment: It is an option, bu it seriously deteriorates the readability of my code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to pass arguments to psycopg2 is to use placeholders and [let the driver handle the values](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). None are converted to NULL automatically and the correct string escaping is performed.

Concatenating string is a [bad idea](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#sql-injection).